# CoovaChilli fails to redirect

Tags: http-redirect, coovachilli

I'm trying to set up a captive portal with CoovaChilli. So far I can get my router to distribute IP address from the 10.1.0.0/24 subnet, but when I attempt to go to www.youtube.com the browser simply hangs. I can access the captive portal only by manually entering 10.1.0.1. The related files are below

```
cat /etc/chilli/config
HS_LANIF=eth1              # Subscriber Interface for client devices
HS_NETWORK=10.1.0.0        # HotSpot Network (must include HS_UAMLISTEN)
HS_NETMASK=255.255.0.0     # HotSpot Network Netmask
HS_UAMLISTEN=10.1.0.1      # HotSpot IP Address (on subscriber network)
HS_UAMPORT=3990            # HotSpot UAM Port (on subscriber network)
HS_UAMUIPORT=4990          # HotSpot UAM "UI" Port (on subscriber network, for embedded portal)
HS_NASID=localhost
HS_RADIUS=localhost
HS_RADIUS2=localhost
HS_RADSECRET=testing123    # Set to be your RADIUS shared secret
HS_UAMSECRET=greatsecret     # Set to be your UAM secret
HS_UAMALIASNAME=chilli
HS_SSID="GreenEarth"
HS_NASIP=127.0.0.1    # To explicitly set NAS-IP-Address
HS_UAMSERVER=$HS_UAMLISTEN
HS_UAMFORMAT=http://\$HS_UAMLISTEN/cake2/rd_cake/dynamic_details/chilli_browser_detect/
HS_MACAUTH=on              # To turn on MAC Authentication
HS_TCP_PORTS="80 23 8000"
HS_MODE=hotspot
HS_TYPE=chillispot
HS_WWWDIR=/etc/chilli/www
HS_WWWBIN=/etc/chilli/wwwsh
HS_PROVIDER=Coova
HS_PROVIDER_LINK=http://www.coova.org/
HS_LOC_NAME="My HotSpot"           # WISPr Location Name and used in portal
HS_COAPORT=3799

cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.1.0.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0

cat /etc/chilli/ipup.sh
iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -o $HS_WANIF -j MASQUERADE

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable https redirect in coovachilli config file:

```
HS_REDIRSSL=on
HS_SSLKEYFILE=/etc/chilli/key.pem
HS_SSLCERTFILE=/etc/chilli/cert.pem
```

To generate certificate files, see [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl).

Also you'll need to have coovachilli build with SSL support enabled.

With this configuration your users should be redirected to the login page when entering https urls (like youtube one).

BUT they will get a browser warning because the certificate won't be the one the browser is waiting for...